issue on redirect to home page after authentication using auth0
My app is not redirecting to the home page after successful authentication; it just gets stuck on the callback page. However, I can access the home page directly through the URL after authentication, and it works perfectly. Please guide me on how to debug this issue.
It shows an error like there is no route for /callback?code=---&state=--- and navigates to the initial route which is /
The following message was thrown:
Could not navigate to initial route.
The requested route name was:
"/callback/?code=\*\*\*\*\*&state=\*\*\*\*"

There was no corresponding route in the app, and so the initial route specified will be
ignored and / will be used instead.
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Auth0 Flutter Web Example',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const LoginPage(),
        '/callback': (context) => const CallbackPage(), // Just a base route
        '/home': (context) => const HomePage(),
      },
    );
  }

I need to navigate to home page after login.
